# Testlink test plan management screen content not displayed

Tags: testlink, test-plan

Configuration:
TestLink 1.9.14

Problem description:
After creating a new test plan in one of my projects in TestLink, I can't see the Test Plan management screen any more.
The page is loaded but not the content.

I've checked in the Event viewer and in the server logs but there is no related logs...

Anyone has ever faced this problem? I guess the new test plan creation has not been performed correctly thus, the table with the test plans can't be mounted and displayed.

Comment: Please add some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Test plan page loads , flashes and show a blank page. The reason is you have added jpg, icons or flash objects in the description of your test plan.

Please remove them. It will work

--Shri